# Autofill section overlaps with KeyboardAvoidingView

Tags: android, react-native

I've been recently struggling with a keyboard issue on android.

The `KeyboardAvoidingView` component is working as expected on both platforms (iOS and Android) **BUT** there is one scenario where the autofill section (on top of the keyboard) overlaps with the content.

**Here is a demo:**

There is no problem if the input already has a value, but if the value is empty, the autofill section will pop up and overlaps with the floating button.

[image: demo]

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?
Either make the `KeyboardAvoidingView` aware of that extra space for the autofill or listen to events in order to make adjustments to my layout (add some padding at the bottom for example).

**More info:**

I'm already subscribed to `keyboardDidShow/keyboardDidHide` events for the image animation.

After trial and error, `behavior: Platform.select({ ios: 'padding', android: null })` worked for me (with the exception of the autofill issue).

The layout looks like this:

```
  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView>
      <ViewLayout>
        {/* Content here */}
      </ViewLayout>
      <Button />
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
```

And here is an Expo Snack with the code example (select Android platform):

https://snack.expo.io/@nico-amabile/autofill-and-keyboardavoidingview

Comment: did you manage to resolve this issue?